# Очищение StringField поля

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtf

вопрос в следующем. У меня есть форма сделанная при помощи Flask-WTF.

```
class DecimalDegrees(FlaskForm):
    decimal_form = StringField(validators=[Regexp(re.compile(r'^[0-9]*[.,]?[0-9]+$'), message='Поле должно содержать только цифры')])
    submit = SubmitField('Перевести')

@app.route('/', methods=["POST", "GET"])
def index():
    form = DecimalDegrees()
    decimal = False
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        decimal = form.decimal_form.data
        form.decimal_form.data = ''
    return render_template('index.html', title='Главная', form=form, decimal=decimal)
```

HTML:

```
<form method="post">
  {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
  {{ form.decimal_form() }}
  {% if form.decimal_form.errors %}
  {% for er in form.decimal_form.errors %}
    {{ er }}
  {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}
  {{ form.submit() }}
</form>
{% if decimal %}
  <p>Вы ввели: {{ decimal }}</p>
{% else %}
  <p>Пока что ничего не ввели.</p>
{% endif %}
```

Когда ввожу цифры, то все хорошо работает, поле очищается. Пробую вводить обычную строку из букв, но поле не очищается. Подскажите в чем ошибка

Answer (score 2):

У вас задан validators с регулярным выражением, который занимается проверкой на цифры (точку/запятую).
А во вьюхе у вас условие `if form.validate_on_submit():`, которое запускает все валидаторы. Когда вы вводите корректное значение, то валидатор возвращает `True` и далее по плану забираете значение и затираете свое введенное значение пустотой `form.decimal_form.data = ''`. Но если вы вводите что-то что не валидно, условие не сработает и форма вернется такой же как вы ее послали при нажатии на кнопку. Это сделанно для того чтобы выводить пользователям ошибки ввода (валидаторов) чтобы их исправляли и уже корректными отправляли.

Вот механизм как обычно делают (псевдокод):

```
@app.route('/', methods=["POST", "GET"])
def index():
    form = DecimalDegrees()
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
        decimal = form.decimal_form.data
        ... some code ...

        return redirect(url_for('success_view'))

    return render_template(
        'index.html', 
        title='Главная', 
        form=form, 
        decimal=decimal
    )
```

То есть, если все корректно отработало вы сохраняете данные или, что вам там нужно делать с введенными пользовательскими данными и в конце удачного исхода обязательно сделать редирект на новую вьюху, или на эту же, но с хорошим ответом (так принято) и это гарантирует корректную работу при простой перезагрузки страницы, чтобы данные пользователя вам много рас не пошли.
Но если валидаторы формы сказали, что значения не верные, то пользователю вернуться заполненные юзером поля с текстами ошибок в `form.decimal_form.errors`, которые вы должны показать в шаблоне, чтобы юзер был в курсе что он ввел не так.